# How to make rownames in two separate data.frames the same?

Tags: r, genome, rda

Please see the picture attached! I am trying to conduct a RDA analysis, but before I proceed I need to make sure my SNP dataset and my Environmental dataset have identical rownames.
I tried editing the individual datasets in excel to satisfy this requirement, and after seemingly making them the same (there is no difference between the rownames anymore), when i type in:
identical(rownames(gen), env)
It still states the rownames matching is "FALSE" when it clearly isn't. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a small typo error. Please try this:

```
identical(rownames(gen), rownames(env))
```

Comment: Also, no need to use excel to assign row names. Simply do `rownames(gen) <- rownames(env)` if the order of rows in both datasets are the same.

Comment: You can also consider to click check mark on the left, just below the down arrow, to let others know that the question is solved. Thanks.